# Installing h5py on an Ubuntu server

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, h5py

I was installing h5py on an Ubuntu server. However it seems to return an error that `h5py.h` is not found. It gives the same error message when I install it using `pip` or the `setup.py` file. What am I missing here?

I have Numpy version 1.8.1, which higher than the required version of 1.6 or above.

The complete output is as follows:

```
van@Hulk:~/h5py-2.3.1⟫ sudo python setup.py install
libhdf5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
HDF5 autodetection failed; building for 1.8.4+
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing h5py.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to h5py.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to h5py.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'h5py.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.c' under directory 'win_include'
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'win_include'
writing manifest file 'h5py.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py
copying h5py/ipy_completer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py
copying h5py/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py
copying h5py/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py
copying h5py/highlevel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/_hl
copying h5py/_hl/group.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/_hl
copying h5py/_hl/files.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/_hl
copying h5py/_hl/selections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/_hl
copying h5py/_hl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/_hl
copying h5py/_hl/filters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/_hl
copying h5py/_hl/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/_hl
copying h5py/_hl/dims.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/_hl
copying h5py/_hl/datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/_hl
copying h5py/_hl/dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/_hl
copying h5py/_hl/selections2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/_hl
copying h5py/_hl/attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/_hl
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_selections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_group.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_h5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_objects.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_slicing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_h5t.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_dimension_scales.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_file.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_h5p.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_attrs_data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
copying h5py/tests/test_h5f.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/tests
running build_ext
skipping 'h5py/defs.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'h5py.defs' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DH5_USE_16_API -I/home/govinda/h5py-2.3.1/lzf -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c h5py/defs.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/h5py/defs.o
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1761:0,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from h5py/api_compat.h:26,
                 from h5py/defs.c:342:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
In file included from h5py/defs.c:342:0:
h5py/api_compat.h:27:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
 #include "hdf5.h"
                  ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You need to install [`libhdf5-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libhdf5-dev) to get the required header files. Just run

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
```

and it should install it and its dependencies automatically.

Don't worry about the NumPy warning, it just means that the package developers are using an old version of the API, but everything will still work.

Comment: I also needed `sudo apt-get install cython` for this to work on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I have 14.04, cython is not installed, but it works after installing only libhdf5-dev.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works for Ubuntu 14.04 using `sudo pip3 install h5py`

Answer (score 22):

You can use [python-h5py](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-h5py).

> sudo apt-get install python-h5py

And then in your Python file try:

> import h5py

Answer (score 19):

In my case (Ubuntu 15.04) installing `libhdf5-dev` was not enough.

I had to run:

`HDF5_DIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/ pip install h5py`

to make it work.

Comment: Thanks! For fellow noobs out there, the HDF5_DIR should be `HDF5_DIR=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/` if you're on Termux.

Answer (score 3):

It is generally preferable to use `pip` instead of installing it manually, since pip will also install all python dependencies. You would still need your header files though.

so:

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
pip install h5py
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to install both `libhdf5-dev` and `cython3` (Ubuntu 18.04 on arm64 device, Python 3.5).

```
sudo apt install libhdf5-dev
sudo apt install cython3
```