# Installing h5py on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, pip, h5py

On Ubuntu 15.04 when I try to install h5py (both pip and setup.py) it complains about lack of hdf5.h file.

I did install `python-dev` and `libhdf5-dev`

`numpy==1.9.2`

`Cython==0.22`

I try to do installation within virtual environment although pip complains also when I try to do global installation.

Full error: http://pastebin.com/C0ECeHHE

Comment: Based on searching the package contents, it looks like the `hdf5.h` file provided by libhdf5-dev has moved from `/usr/include/` to `/usr/include/hdf5/serial/`: I don't know if this is significant.

Comment: I tried to inform installer about location of a file by `HDF5_DIR=/usr/include/hdf5/serial/ pip install h5py` but I got the same error.

Comment: I was about to suggest exactly that: perhaps if you edited your post to include the exact error message (with more context - not just "it complains") it would give more clues?

Comment: Your idea with HDF5_DIR was already very close, but the dir you need is `HDF5_DIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/ pip install h5py`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing h5py on an Ubuntu server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744969/installing-h5py-on-an-ubuntu-server)